# WCF POST not working but GET working

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I have a RESTful service with WCF. It has an interface with a method

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "AddBook/{bookName}", BodyStyle =     WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
void AddBook(string bookName);
```

and my service localhost:1234/MService/AddBook/abcd-book is working. But if I change GET to POST, it says method not allowed. I thought, inserting should be POST but it is not working. Am I wrong or doing something wrong with the coding above?

Regards

Comment: Your method is only allowing GET according to the attribute.   'WebInvoke(Method = "GET"'

Comment: But if I change that GET to POST and try to add book from URL, it says method not allowed.

Comment: REmove it all together like this: WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "AddBook/{bookName}", BodyStyle =     WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)

Comment: Thank you John. But I tried that already without success.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153700/can-wcf-restful-service-allow-same-method-expose-as-webget-and-webinvoke

Comment: What do you mean by `try to add book from URL`? Do you type the URL on a browser window? How do you create your POST request?

Comment: @YK1: I think that is the problem. I tried POST request like GET with URL on a browser window.

Comment: Yes, typing URL in browser will send GET request by default. To send a POST request, either create a HTML form or use tool like Fiddler.

Comment: Can you post your comment as answer so that I can mark it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typing URL in browser will send GET request by default. To send a POST request, either create a HTML form or use tool like Fiddler.